# add transition effect in vue on backgroundImage

Tags: css, vue.js, background-image

I've been searching for a couple of days to add a fade transition effect on the backgroundImage that I'm changing through a Vue app.

Here is the code snippet I've been testing on:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    images: [
      "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/bfd/clouds-1371838.jpg",
      "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/ffa/water-lilly-1368676.jpg",
      "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/efb/lotus-flower-1382251.jpg"
    ],
    current: 0,
    show: false
  },
  methods: {
    changeBG: function () {
      if (this.current < this.images.length - 1) {
        this.current = this.current + 1;
      } else {
        this.current = 0;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;   
  background-position: center 0px; 
} 
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 10px; 
}
p.hello{
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.fade-enter-to,
.fade-leave {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* hello example transition */
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
}
.slide-fade-enter,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<transition name="fade">
  <div v-if="changeBG" class="main" id="main" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(\'' + images[current] + '\')' }">
    <button v-on:click="changeBG">
      changeBG
    </button>
    <div id="testFromGuide">
      <button @click="show = !show">
        toggleHello
      </button>
      <transition name="slide-fade">
        <p class="hello" v-if="show">all your base are belong to us</p>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</transition>
```

My first question if this is simply possible? The reason I'm using backgroundImage is because the website I'm using this on has a background that is most easy to handle responsively through this (always covering, no repeat and keeping it center). And my scond question would be, if not, is there a possibility to make it work with a background set as described [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)?

In the codepen I've added an example of the [vue guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) to make sure it works and nothing is else is wrong. And the example works perfectly. Can't seem to find the answer for my example but I've been beginning to suspect it is simply not possible or I can't seem to find why vue isn't detecting something is changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Vue Transitions to work, you need to change the DOM elements. So this way would work if you were changing actual images out. In your example, you're only changing an attribute value. The DOM doesn't trigger a transition since its the same element.

**However, you can use the `:key` attribute to convince VUE to replace the element thus giving you a transition between 2 elements.**

You can also set the image with inline CSS like you're doing in the example. You'll still have to create the transition in your CSS.

Here's an example using Vue Transition

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
  currentID: 0,
    images: [
'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/efb/lotus-flower-1382251.jpg',
'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/ffa/water-lilly-1368676.jpg',
'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/bfd/clouds-1371838.jpg'
  ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggleImage: function(){
       if(this.currentID < this.images.length-1){
     this.currentID +=1
    } else {
     this.currentID = 0
    }     
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}

button {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 20px;
}

/* prefix with transition name */
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide-fade-enter,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" id="main">
    <transition name="slide-fade">
<!--    SRC comes from the array of images the :key is important for vue to believe its a 'new' DOM element and do the transition -->
      <img v-bind:src="images[currentID]" v-bind:key="currentID" />
    </transition>
 <button @click="toggleImage">
      Toggle Image
    </button>
</div>
```

However, you don't get a lot of control over that since it uses image tags. Instead, it might be better to use a background image like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
  currentID: 0,
    images: [
'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/efb/lotus-flower-1382251.jpg',
'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/ffa/water-lilly-1368676.jpg',
'https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/bfd/clouds-1371838.jpg'
  ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggleImage: function(){
       if(this.currentID < this.images.length-1){
     this.currentID +=1
    } else {
     this.currentID = 0
    }     
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  /* make this the size of the window */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.theImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}

button {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 20px;
}

/* prefix with transition name */
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide-fade-enter,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" id="main">
    <transition name="slide-fade">
<!--    SRC comes from the array of images the :key is important for vue to believe its a 'new' DOM element and do the transition -->
   <div class="theImage" v-bind:style="{'background-image': 'url(' + images[currentID] + ')'}" v-bind:key="currentID"></div>
    </transition>
 <button @click="toggleImage">
      Toggle Image
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: A very cryptic answer and hard to understand for an amateur like me but it made me find a solution that works the hard way.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to build an example. Looks like you found a solution but I'm happy to add an example if it would be useful.

Comment: no need for sorry, learning the hard way can have it's benefits in the long run, the solution not perfect (see answer here-under), also I'm having problems mimicking the background: cover css property for an <img> element :)

Comment: You did kind of do it the hard way. I'll build an example and edit my answer. You might want to use a div instead of an img as you'll get a lot more CSS control.

Comment: There's an example of using the reactive data properties in Vue to get the transition. Basically you're just replacing an attribute and setting a `:key` value to let Vue do the transition.

Comment: If you need a unique class for example on image #2 you can use `v-bind:class="currentID == 1 ? 'classNameToAddIfTrue' : 'classNameToAddIfFalse' "`

Comment: Thank you for both examples! I did find a way to get the same result for an <img> as for background-image in a <div> (the key was the object-fit: cover property, no IE11 support though). Too many options now but I will definitely  use 1 of both your answers. Much appreciated!

Comment: I ended up combining the two, a <div> with changing background-image and a <img> with changing src on top of it, triggered by the same button (which contains the <img>), but it doesn't seem the transition for the <img> works, the <div> transition works fine! couldn't find the problem yet, am I correct you can use <transition name="fade"> multiple times?

Comment: Yes you can reuse transitions. Make sure the image or div is getting a z-index where the new one is higher AND make sure that ALL the transitioned elements have a unique key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212362/discussion-between-stijn-van-der-linden-and-bryce-howitson).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was indeed to forget about vue transitions and let css do the work. A working example can be found here:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    show: false,
    BG1: true,
    BG2: false,
    BG3: false
  },
  methods: {
    changeBG: function(){
     if (this.BG1 == true){
    this.BG1 = false;
    this.BG2 = true;
        this.BG3 = false;
   } else if (this.BG2 == true) {
    this.BG1 = false;
    this.BG2 = false;
        this.BG3 = true;
   } else if (this.BG3 == true) {
    this.BG1 = true;
    this.BG2 = false;
        this.BG3 = false;
   }       
    },
    showBG1: function(){
   if (this.BG1 == true){
    return "";
   } else {
    return "transparent";
   }
    },
    showBG2: function(){
   if (this.BG2 == true){
    return "";
   } else {
    return "transparent";
   }
    },
    showBG3: function(){
   if (this.BG3 == true){
    return "";
   } else {
    return "transparent";
   }
    }    
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
} 

#bgs img.transparent {
  opacity:0;
  transform: translateY(-0.0px);
}

#bgs img{
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
 
  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 
  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  #bgs img{
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}

button {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 20px; 
}
p.hello{
  color: white;
  margin: 40px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to{
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  opacity: 0;
}

/* hello example transition */
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
}
.slide-fade-enter,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" id="main">
  <div id="bgs">
    <img :class="showBG1()" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/efb/lotus-flower-1382251.jpg">
    <img :class="showBG2()" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/ffa/water-lilly-1368676.jpg">
   <img :class="showBG3()" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/bfd/clouds-1371838.jpg">
  </div>
  <button @click="changeBG">
    changeBG
  </button>
  <div id="testFromGuide">
    <button @click="show = !show">
      toggleHello
    </button>
    <transition name="slide-fade">
      <p class="hello" v-if="show">all your base are belong to us</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's not perfect yet as for every extra background I need to add a function and add an extra *if else* loop to the changeBG function. It would be more elegant if this could be done with a list variable but I've not found a way to make this work with the :class method. I hope to look into this at a later time.